# Get all tasks in Teams planner of users using graph API

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the tasks in planner of my team onto Power BI using Graph API.

I am able to retrieve my own tasks:

[my tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8PJp.jpg)

But I am not able to retrieve tasks of my team member using their ID:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6fK6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph API doesn't allow you to access tasks for any other user than your own user.  There is no permission that can be granted to allow this. If you want to do that you will need to that "user" to use your application so you access access that api from that user point of view.

Normally in the Graph API if you needed to do something like this you would get the application permission but the graph planner API doesn't support the application permission so we are stuck with what it does provide (only user delegated permission).

There are some user voice requests asking for application permission for the tasks API you may like to vote on.

- [application permissions to task api](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/5904632-application-permissions-to-task-api)
- [add support for application permissions on planner](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40477918-add-support-for-application-permissions-on-planner)